# Clueless Alphabetical

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle, crosswords

Crosswords are harder when you don't know the clues.

[image]

The solution can be found in the grey shaded boxes.
<sub>(How many four letter words are there starting with Z, again?)</sub>

Comment: What dictionary are we using here? Are you sure the solution is unique?

Comment: @JoeZ There is a logical relationship between all the words in the grid. Yes, there is a unique solution. There are a few hints in the title and the question body, too ;)

Comment: Is the question about z words a cryptic clue to what the z word is?

Comment: @AndrewSmith No, but the limited number of Z words might help narrow down what the pattern of words can be. It might also help to count how many words there are in the grid.

Comment: 26 including the 2 grey answers, I guessed each word started with a different letter from the title

Comment: @AndrewSmith Each word has a relationship, not just the first letter :P

Comment: @Tryth ah cool, got it. Can't be bothered filling it out on my phone though lol

Comment: @Tryth is the grid wrong? Looks like the 2 letter word in the top left is the same as the 2 letter word going down from the 5 letter word

Comment: @AndrewSmith I suspect your 7-letter top left word is wrong.

Comment: @Tryth there are 4 2 letter answers with only 3 to choose from?

Comment: The 2 without grey boxes have the same answer as far as I can tell, though I'm doing it mentally xD

Comment: @AndrewSmith There *are* four 2 letter answers. I'm not even sure if you have the right set of words anymore :P

Comment: @Tryth aha, the page I was using for reference was missing one of the two, crisis averted!

Comment: There are zero four-letter Z words.

Comment: ^ What about "zero"?

Comment: There's actually 35 4 letter z words..I play too much online scrabble.  Zags Zany Zaps Zarf Zeal Zebu Zeds Zees Zein Zeks Zeps Zerk Zero Zest Zeta Zigs Zill Zinc Zine Zing Zins Zips Ziti Zits Zoea Zoic Zona Zone Zonk Zoom Zoon Zoos Zori Zouk Zyme

Comment: Only 2 of those could form a pattern with at least 23 other possible related answers, only 1 provides a pattern that includes 2 letter words

Comment: @JoeZ I was being facetious, obviously.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The answers are all

> Letters from the Greek alphabet

Giving the grey boxes as

> M,n,g,e,i,a

Rearranging to

> Enigma

Comment: @Tryth is that better?

Comment: Could the word be enigma?

Comment: Well spotted @NinjaBearMonkey